# Drag and Drop takes over my scrollbar

Tags: javascript, html, css, dojo

I have a div and inside my div I have a dojo dijit.layout.BorderContainer. Inside that border container I have 2 more more BorderContainers and finally each of those border containers has one more BorderContainer.

The base div is made movable with dojo.dnd.movable. This works fine and I can move my div about my screen properly. My problem arises in the most nested BorderContaienrs. Each of these contains many buttons and have the overflow:auto. When I grab the scroll bar to scroll down to see more of my buttons the scroll bar doesn't work. Instead when I grab the scroll bar and move it down/up it drags the entire div around the screen. I have checked the z-index and the scroll bar is most certainly above the div.

Here is the hierarchy 
div/BorderContainer/BorderContainer/Bordercontainer(with scroll bar)

Comment: Just a question here: Could you create your many borders with pure CSS, or is the hierarchy you have obligatory?

I fail to understand why so many BorderContainer elements would be needed in the first place.

Comment: I am playing with it right now and have removed all of the border containers so just my button lists (with the overflow) and the scroll bar and other essentials are left. This did not change the behavior of the drag and drop.

Comment: All of this is created in java script.